# Spark aggregate value from multi dimension array column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The dataset contains one multi-dimension array column with parent and child relation between columns, and need to aggregate that.

Data (example) -

```
|consumerId|    device  |       impressions        
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |123abc    |   Phone   |  [[1123, 'container', 1, 0, [10:00 AM]],[1124, 'item', 2, 1, [10:01 AM, 10:02 AM]],[1125, 'container', 3, 0, [10:05 AM]]]
 |123abc    |   TV      |  [[1123, 'container', 1, 0, [11:00 AM]],[1128, 'item', 2, 1, [11:01 AM, 11:12 AM]],[1129, 'item', 3, 1, [11:05 AM]]
 |123abc    |   Phone   |  [[1130, 'container', 1, 0, [12:00 AM]],[1131, 'item', 2, 1, [12:01 AM]]]
```

Input Schema-

```
 |-- consumerId: string
 |-- platform: string 
 |-- impressions: array
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)                 // same "id" will be treated as "containerId" and "itemId"
 |    |    |-- impressionType: string (nullable = true)     // Decide factor "container" or "item"
 |    |    |-- impressionId: long (nullable = true)         // postion - item will be identified by "impressions.impressionParentId = impressions.impressionId“ 
 |    |    |-- impressionParentId: long (nullable = true)   // relation between container & it's items as above
 |    |    |-- impressionTimes: array (nullable = true)     // Need to check Max time
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Output Schema-

```
 |-- consumerId: string
 |-- platform: string 
 |-- impressions: array                
 |   |-- containerId: integer          // If impressions.impressionType='container' then it's "id" will containerID
 |   |-- itemImpressions: array        // List of all impressions id (as itemId) where "impressionParentId = conainer.impressionId“
 |   |   |-- itemId: long              // "impressions.id" if  "impressions.impressionParentId = impressions.impressionId“
 |   |   |-- lastImpressionTime: long  // max(impressionTimes)
 |   |   |-- impressionCount: int
```

> Few points-

1. Each row contains multi dimension array field - **impressions**
2. ***impressions*** contains both **container** and related **items** and these relationship can be found by `impressions.impressionParentId = impressions.impressionId` [ I believe that it needs to do self join to establish the relation]
3. if **explode** all record, then not able to establish the container and its items relationship as **impressionId** is same as location in each row.
4. If `impressions.impressionType='container'` then it's "id" will **containerID** in output schema
5. Three level of aggregation -

   - First by **consumerId** and platform
   - Second by **containerId**
   - Third by **itemId**, total counts and Max(impressionTimes)

The above example is from filtered datasets, and I tried to explode and aggregate, but it's not working.

Comment: Please edit and include your code in the post, that would help determining the issue.

Comment: Edited and updated the example